# What can i do to get my cloned WhatsApp to show messages with names from my contacts (address book) in a Huawei 40P lite smart phone?

Tags: samsung, contacts, whatsapp-messenger, huawei

I transferred my phone contacts from my old Samsung phone into a new Huawei 40P lite. The phone doesnt come with pre-installed WhatsApp. I then cloned WhatsApp from the old Samsung phone. The address book is showng pretty well but the names in my contacts havent synched with the WhatsApp. What should i do to activatte the address book (contacts) so that the WhatsApp messages should be showing the names of the people in my contacts list.

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps?
https://drfone.wondershare.com/whatsapp/whatsapp-not-showing-contact-names.html

1. Turn on your contact permissions
2. Refresh WhatsApp Contact List
3. Reset WhatsApp Sync